# How to print data from a csv file on a browser in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to read a csv file and whenever someone connects to my server it prints the content of the file in their browser.

I have this module called 'lecture_csv' that lets me read the file and directly print it in the terminal:

```
var csv = require('csv-parser')
var fs = require('fs')


function lecture_csv(fileName) {
    fs.createReadStream(fileName)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
    //console.log(row)
    return row;
    })
    .on('end', () => {
    console.log('fichier lu');
    });  
}

exports.lecture_csv = lecture_csv
```

What I want is to print 'row' on the client browser.

However in my main:

```
let lecture = require('./lecture_csv');
var http = require('http');
//let app = require('./app');

var fileName = 'test_file.csv'
var string = ''
//lecture.lecture_csv(fileName);

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write(lecture.lecture_csv(fileName));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

I have an error saying I can't use res.write as the parameter in undefined instead of a string.
Is there a way to get 'row' and print it on the client browser?

I am still very new to nodejs therefore any tips is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read file and send its contents ,like below

```
let lecture = require('./lecture_csv');
let fs=require("fs");
var http = require('http');
var fileName = './test_file.csv'
var string = ''
//lecture.lecture_csv(fileName);

http.createServer(function(req, res){

   fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.write(contents);
     res.end();
});

}).listen(9000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, the only detail was to exchange 'lecture' with 'fileName' in the fs.readFile().